# Inlining functions from multiple assembly files in LLVM

Tags: function, llvm, llvm-ir, inlining

I have multiple .s files, which contain LLVM IR code generated separately from corresponding high level Ada code. There are function calls across these files. Is there a way to inline a function in a different .s file?

Comment: Usually you do this by mean of link time optimisation.

Comment: I need to do some analysis on the .s file. So, is there a way to use some attribute/ pass in LLVM to do the inlining?

Comment: I am unaware of any such method.  You could link the two together and then manually perform an inlining pass with `llvm-opt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO, Ranjani!

You can try linking those files together using [`llvm-link`](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-link.html), e.g.:

```
llvm-link -S -o merged.ll foo.ll bar.ll
```

The command will link two files `foo.ll` and `bar.ll` and write the result into `merged.ll`. The `-S` option tells the linker to emit bitcode in the human-readable form.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I will try it and see if it serves my purpose. Can any number of files be merged this way?

Comment: I tried now. There seems to be no issue even if I link multiple files. Thank you!